# setting file owner of a xib file

Tags: ios, objective-c

Hi I am reading a book where I had to deal with such situation.
I created a XIB file named `HeaderView.xib.` Then I connected the `File Owner` of this XIB
file to `ItemsViewController`. All is fine so far. I also connected
some outlets of the ItemsViewController with views on the XIB.

Now, in the `ItemsViewController` I had to call such code:

```
- (UIView *)headerView
{
    // If we haven't loaded the headerView yet...
    if (!headerView) {
        // Load HeaderView.xib
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"HeaderView" owner:self options:nil];
    }

    return headerView;
}
```

Code above would set `headerView` outlet of `ItemsViewController` point to the corresponding
view on the XIB file (the one I made connections with on XIB file).
My question is, why did I have to, ***two times***, specify the owner? (e.g., once in the XIB as I mentioned in the start of this port, and second time, above in the code, e.g., `owner: self`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You did not specify the file owner twice:

- The first time (in the XIB file) you specified the *type* of the file owner; this is necessary for the Interface Builder to know which outlets it can connect.
- The second time (in the Objective C code) you specified the *instance* of the owner. This is necessary at runtime to know the object into which the outlets are connected.

Comment: dasblinkenlight, let me ask you such question then. If I set the File Owner of some XIB to a ViewController. And then (in the XIB) connect the View outlet of the ViewController to some view in the XIB file. Then that is all I have to do in that case. I don't have usually to make that call as above in the code anymore. Why is it? (is it because somewhere automatically loadNibNamed gets called in case of ViewController's view?)?

Comment: @user2054339 There are other ways of loading XIBs implicitly - for example, if your view controller is instantiated using `initWithNibName`, there is no need to call the `loadNibNamed:` method.

Comment: @ dasblinkenlight: Yes, I tested it just added a ViewController. Then a XIB file. Set the file owner of the XIB file to my ViewController. Then, in the XIB connected view outlet of the ViewController to my view in the XIB. and the view is automatically loaded, no need to call loadNibNamed anymore... I have to call loadNibNamed here apparently because it is a different outlet.. also  for different class TableViewController...

Comment: The outlet isn't the key piece of information here and you're getting confused. For your `ViewController`, how are you creating the controller? In some cases it will load a view without an XIB file, in some cases it will look for an XIB with a set name (the same name as the class).

Comment: @Wain: yes, and when it loads the XIB with same name as class - you only have to connect the File Owner in the XIB and that suffices. because apparently UIViewController calls loadNibNamed somewhere internally for the main `view`. Here I had to do it manually..

Answer (score 3):

Specifying the owner in the XIB tells Xcode what the controller understands (what outlets it has) so that it can offer the connections to you. This is at a class level.

Specifying the owner in code tells the unarchiving process which instance of the controller is actually going to fulfil that role and should therefore have the connections established to the new instance(s) which are unarchived from the NIB.

Answer (score 1):

I found it... When the world is not using XIB(s) anymore... 
Open the XIB or NIB file in your favourite text editor

you will find this line there...

```
        <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFilesOwner" id="-1" userLabel="File's Owner" customClass="MyCalssName">
```

Change the class name, save the file and your file's owner will be changed.
Caution: Close Xcode (To auto reload the changes) and also take a backup in case you mess up something.